# How to loop in list data type in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, csv, lapply

I'm trying to use R to extract one column (variable) from each data.frame in a list data type. I need to loop for this as I have 650 files.

I applied `lapply` first to import all the csv files and the list data looks like this

```
data1 <- lapply(dir(),read.csv) 

head(data1) 

[[1]] 
X Y Range Displacement 

[[2]]

X Y Range Displacement

.

.

.
```

I want to extract Range columns from the 650 files. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: does each file contains the same number of rows ?

Comment: yes, each dataframe has the same number of rows and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data.table is a good package for stuff like this, especially since it has the super fast fread() function to read files.

Something like this should give you a data table (which is also a data frame):

```
data1 <- rbindlist(lapply(dir(), fread))
```